# Continous deployments for on prem databases with Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, continuous-deployment

Everyone, I'm looking on a way to deploy updates to our on prem databases using Azure DevOps and I'm running into a roadblock on the release definition.  I have my DACPAC ready to go, but not sure how to get that over to my on prem server.

I see the WinRM-SQL Server DB Deployment as a task, but not sure how to set that up.  I have seen a couple of videos that use the SQL Server Database Deploy as an option, but it looks like that task has been deprecated, so it looks like I will need to use the WinRM-SQL task.  So, could anyone point me in the right direction on how to set this task up to use my local SQL server or possibly a tutorial that help get me started?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?  I am just now looking into this for our pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

You will also have to install a [release agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops) on the target server where you will be deploying the database, assign it to a Deployment Group, create your release pipeline template and then run a release. I wrote a blog post about how to deploy a database to an on-prem SQL Server by leveraging Azure DevOps: https://jpvelasco.com/deploying-a-sql-server-database-onto-an-on-prem-server-using-azure-devops/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you already created a Deployment Group, within your Pipeline:

1. Click to Add a new stage: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc5TI.png
2. On the right side, (SELECT A TEMPLATE screen) type SQL in the search box
3. Select: IIS website and SQL database deployment, this will add a Stage with Two tasks: IIS deployment and SQL DB Deploy.
4. Delete the IIS Deployment Task
5. Configure the SQL DB Deploy task - It does not say it is deprecated.